# How do i locate the variable that is the mismatch (Run-time error 13)

Tags: excel, vba, mismatch

I'm trying to locate the variable mismatch in this code for my coworkers VBA code. Yet i've not been able to locate the problem. The code is supposed to update 2 different sheets based on manual inputs in a 3rd sheet. This is in regard to safety hazards.

The debug says this line of code is the one messing up

```
 Previouscellcontentbefore = ActiveCell.Offset(rowbefore + 1, columbefore + 1)
```

The full code:

```
Dim I As Integer
Dim row As Integer
Dim before As String
Dim after As String
Dim cons As String
Dim conscat As String
Dim checks As String
Dim check2 As String
Dim check3 As String
Dim rowbefore As String
Dim columbefore As String
Dim rowafter As String
Dim columafter As String
Dim checkbefore As String
Dim checkafter As String
Dim Previouscellcontentbefore As Integer
Dim Previouscellcontentafter As Integer



Sheets("for calculations").Visible = True

cons = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Personnel; Environment; Assets; Reputation; All", Title:="Choose consequence (NB: Case sensitive)", Default:="All")
Worksheets("For calculations").Activate

Range("D37:I42").ClearContents
Range("L37:Q42").ClearContents
Range("C34").ClearContents

Select Case cons

    Case "All"
        Range("C34").Value = "Risk matrix shows all types of consequences"
    Case "Personnel"
        Range("C34").Value = "Risk matrix shows all types of Personnel consequences"
    Case "Environment"
        Range("C34").Value = "Risk matrix shows Environmental consequences"
    Case "Asset"
        Range("C34").Value = "Risk matrix shows Asset consequences"
    Case "Reputation"
        Range("C34").Value = "Risk matrix shows Reputation consequences"
End Select


For I = 1 To 200
    Range("C47").Value = Worksheets("HAZIDS").Cells(I + 5, 2).Value
    conscat = Range("F47")
    check2 = cons Like conscat
    check3 = cons Like "All"

If cons Like "All" Then
    check2 = True
End If

    If check2 Then

before = Range("D47")
after = Range("E47")
rowbefore = Mid(before, 2, 1)
columbefore = Mid(before, 4, 1)
rowafter = Mid(after, 2, 1)
columafter = Mid(after, 4, 1)

checkbefore = Not rowbefore Like "" And Not columbefore Like ""
checkafter = Not rowafter Like "" And Not columafter Like ""

    If checkbefore Then
        Range("C36").Select
        Previouscellcontentbefore = ActiveCell.Offset(CInt(rowbefore) + 1, CInt(columbefore) + 1)
        ActiveCell.Offset(CInt(rowbefore) + 1, CInt(columbefore) + 1) = Range("C47").Value & ", " & Previouscellcontentbefore

    If checkafter Then
        Range("K36").Select
        Previouscellcontentafter = ActiveCell.Offset(CInt(rowafter) + 1, CInt(columafter) + 1)
          ActiveCell.Offset(CInt(rowafter) + 1, CInt(columafter) + 1) = Range("C47").Value & ", " & Previouscellcontentafter

        End If
    End If
End If


End Sub
```

I expect the macro to update sheet "Risk matrix before" and "Risk matrix after" based on the manual inputs in "HAZIDS"
Yet the sheet "For calculations" seems to be buggy

Comment: Lot of things can be wrong here. Use `Option Explicit` and please fully declare your variables. `rowbefore + 1`, rowbefore should be a long but you are storing a string in it? `rowbefore = Mid(before, 2, 1)`?

Comment: If you are planning to use it for "Addition" then declare it as long. This will replicate the problem and emphasize on proper variable declaration. `Dim rw As Long: rw = "Sid"`

Comment: Reason why it is strings is due to strings having pre-set values in "for calculations" sheet. Therefor it concatenates strings.

Comment: Then convert them to long before you use it for aditions. This way you will know if there is any invalid value in them...

Answer (score 0):

You are doing

```
rowbefore = Mid(before, 2, 1) 'Rownumber in matrix before
columbefore = Mid(before, 4, 1) 'Columnumber in matrix before
```

And since you didn't declare these variables, they get a string value. (since `Mid` return a string)

After that in the line indicated by the debug you do this:

```
Previouscellcontentbefore = ActiveCell.Offset(rowbefore + 1, columbefore + 1)
```

You are adding integer value 1 to a string value, which doesn't make sense.

What you need to do is use `option explicit` and properly define your variables.
Then you might need to convert your strings into integers with the function Cint like this

```
Previouscellcontentbefore = ActiveCell.Offset(Cint(rowbefore) + 1, Cint(columbefore) + 1)
```

This will only work if your `rowbefore` and `columnbefore` actually contain a string that can be converted to an integer. If not you will get an error.

Comment: I've now defined all my variables (as what i expect i to be searching the sheet. This is not my excel sheet, just trying to fix it.) and updated the code slightly, though now i'm getting an error for "for I = 1 to 200 can't be executed without "next"

Comment: then you add a `next` statement at the end of the loop. If you can't figure it out, and you can't find the answer here already, please post a new question with the new problem.